# Dynamic Data Scheme for ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have read through the tutorials for ASP.NET Dynamic Data and they all require that you create a static data context.

That is you have to generate a data model using Entity Framework or Linq to SQL and if the scheme for that model ever changes then you need to go into Visual Studio and change the model accordingly.

I am looking for a solution that will handle the changes in scheme (ie new table or new column) without having to rebuild in visual studio.

Is this possible using ASP.NET Dynamic Data?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, your choices are: Entity Framework or Linq to SQL. Both generate a bunch of classes with getter and setter properties and attributes which detail meta data, this is done automatically when you drag and drop database tables onto the Data Context.

I don't think there is a third option, and even if you could code it 'certainly wouldn't be trivial, redoing the Data Context after changing the database would be easier and take less time in total.

Although I appreciate database tables and columns do change, surely frequent database changes disrupt the service to the end users?

The only workaround would be to run SqlMetal [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in some automated fashion e.g. scheduled task running PowerShell script or batch file. However this will require a re-compile and re-deploy which will also interrupt the end users, unless it is done when nobody is using it.

Plus it would only give you really basic New, View, Edit screens - don't see how they would be useful for anything other than a really quick and dirty application.

It would be cool if dynamic data could do what you're asking though.

**You can use SqlMetal.exe from the command line to generate the classes, I believe Visual Studio does this behind the scenes.**